# Is Stream.resource only from, not to?

Tags: elixir

Reading through the documentation, [`Stream.resource`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Stream.html#resource/3) seems only intended for creating a resource that one can read/get values from, not write/put to. Have I understood correctly or am I reading it wrong? And if I've understand it correctly, what type of resource must I create to write/put to from a stream, a `Collectable`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have read the documentation correctly, `Stream.resource` is only a convenience method for emitting values. It is also correct that if you want to consume values, you need to implement the `Collectable` protocol. You can look into the [source code of `File.Stream`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/e47b5587aac9997aeddb06055b089956852c2d25/lib/elixir/lib/file/stream.ex), which implements both `Enumerable` and `Collectable`.

For demonstration purposes, here’s a `ChunkedWriter` module that stores values until the buffer is full, then flushes it when the limit is reached:

```
defmodule ChunkedWriter do
  def open(chunk_size) do
    Agent.start_link fn -> {[], chunk_size} end
  end

  def write(agent, value) do
    Agent.update agent, fn {old_buffer, chunk_size} ->
      buffer = [value | old_buffer]
      new_buffer = cond do
        length(buffer) < chunk_size -> buffer
        true -> do_flush(buffer)
      end
      {new_buffer, chunk_size}
    end
  end

  def flush(agent) do
    Agent.update agent, fn {buffer, chunk_size} ->
      {do_flush(buffer), chunk_size}
    end
  end

  defp do_flush(buffer) do
    buffer |> Enum.reverse |> Enum.each(&IO.puts/1)
    IO.puts "---"
    []
  end

  def close(agent) do
    flush(agent)
    Agent.stop(agent)
  end

  def stream(chunk_size) do
    %ChunkedWriter.Stream{chunk_size: chunk_size}
  end
end
```

This module would be used like this:

```
writer = ChunkedWriter.open(3)

ChunkedWriter.write(writer, 1)
ChunkedWriter.write(writer, 2)
ChunkedWriter.write(writer, 3)
ChunkedWriter.write(writer, 4)
ChunkedWriter.write(writer, 5)

ChunkedWriter.close(writer)
```

This outputs

```
1
2
3
---
4
5
---
```

Now the `ChunkedWriter.stream/1` method just sets up a struct which will then be dispatched to `ChunkedWriter.Stream`. Here is the `ChunkedWriter.Stream` module with its `Collectable` implementation, so we can pipe an `Enumerable` into it.

```
defmodule ChunkedWriter.Stream do
  defstruct chunk_size: 1

  defimpl Collectable do
    def into(stream = %ChunkedWriter.Stream{chunk_size: chunk_size}) do
      {:ok, writer} = ChunkedWriter.open(chunk_size)
      {stream, fn
        _acc, {:cont, value} ->
          ChunkedWriter.write(writer, value)
        _acc, :done ->
          :ok = ChunkedWriter.close(writer)
          stream
        _, :halt ->
          :ok = ChunkedWriter.close(writer)
      end}
    end
  end
end
```

In action:

```
Stream.cycle([1,2,3])
|> Stream.take(10)
|> Stream.into(ChunkedWriter.stream(4))
|> Stream.run
```

This prints:

```
1
2
3
1
---
2
3
1
2
---
3
1
---
```

Answer (score 4):

You are correct. Stream.resource/3 is a convenience for defining sources. Underneath, Stream.resource/3 implements an Enumerable, which is the protocol all sources (and transformers like map) implement.

The Enumerable protocol is really good about taking values out of things and passing them forward, however it doesn't work for collecting those values into something sensible. For that you'd implement the Collectable protocol.

Well, you may wonder, what if you want both?

You can look into the `File.Stream` or `GenEvent.Stream` implementations in Elixir code for an example. In short, assuming you have a `MyData` module, you could define a `MyData.stream/0` function that will return a `%MyData.Stream{}` struct that implements both `Enumerable` and `Collectable` protocols, allowing you to provide both mechanisms.